# significant change & methods called

Tags: ios

I wonder what method in Appdelgate get called after other than "didUpdateToLocation"

for example, would the method:

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
applicationDidEnterBackground
applicationDidBecomeActive

get called when there is a significant change location update event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of Core Location and the "significant change location update event" you are looking for can be found in [CLLocationManagerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html).

Maybe the [`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateToLocation%3afromLocation%3a) delegate method is what you are looking for?